Why does Dear ImGui Tables inserts extra ID into the id path of child widgets?
// ID conflict. Expected behaviour.
static float value1;
static float value2;

ImGui::DragFloat("##drag-float", &value1);  // .../##drag-float
ImGui::DragFloat("##drag-float", &value2);  // .../##drag-float

If either of the DragFloats are changed, the other DragFloat will get updated, which is expected since they both share the same id during runtime (in comment)
However, I expected the following code to have the same behaviour. But it doesn't.
// No ID conflict. Unexpected behaviour.
static float table_value1;
static float table_value2;

if (ImGui::BeginTable("table", 1)) {
    ImGui::TableNextRow();
    ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(0);
    ImGui::DragFloat("##drag-float", &table_value1); // .../table/##drag-float
    ImGui::EndTable();
}
if (ImGui::BeginTable("table", 1)) {
    ImGui::TableNextRow();
    ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(0);
    ImGui::DragFloat("##drag-float", &table_value2);  // .../table/0x8CD5DC7A [override]/##drag-float
    ImGui::EndTable();
}

In the second case ImGui adds 0x8CD5DC7A [override] between the table id and the DragFloat id.
The reason I don't want this behaviour is because I want to create my own wrapper widgets that will make use of the ImGui Tables API and I also want to support the "label" behaviour as the ImGui Widgets (i.e., if there's "##" in the label then display label is the substring before that and id is the entire thing. If there's "###" in the label then display label is the substring before that and id is the substring after that).
So, when I create my custom widgets like this:
void WrapperWidget(const std::string& label, float& value) {
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> label_id_pair = extractLabelAndId(label);

    ImGui::PushID(label_id_pair.second.c_str());

    ImGui::Text(label_id_pair.first.c_str());
    ImGui::SameLine();

    if (ImGui::BeginTable("table", 1)) {
        ImGui::TableNextRow();
        ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(0);
        ImGui::DragFloat("##drag-float", &value);  // .../table/0x8CD5DC7A [override]/##drag-float
        ImGui::EndTable();
    }

    ImGui::PopID();
}

static float value1;
static float value2;
WrapperWidget("WrapDrag1###ID", value1);
WrapperWidget("WrapDrag2###ID", value2);  // Supposed to have the same id as the previous one.

I want them to conflict with one another when they share same ID-just like native ImGui widgets. How do I achieve that behaviour?

I also had this issue where I wanted 2 inputs to be the same and have an ID conflict. Both were also inside a table.
Looking deeper it has to do with instance_no in the bool ImGui::BeginTableEx function of ImGui. I haven't found a solution to your problem, I fixed mine with just not using tables.

Because ImGui ID stack system works this way. Windows and some Widgets affect the resulting ID hash, which allows to have same named/IDed non-conflicting ImGui::DragFloat("##drag-float", &value) within different widgets.
If you want to synchronize them - ensure that the exact same ID (hash) being pushed for your DragFloats with PushOverrideID() from <imgui_internal.h> (saw this on Synced tables across windows? GitHub issue).
Also: some widgets provides a flag to avoid pushing the ID onto the stack, like for Tab Items: ImGuiTabItemFlags_NoPushId for BeginTabItem().
